# MySQL Online DDL Index Creation

Tags: mysql, index, ddl, online-operations

I have a table with 25 million records and 10 columns on which I am trying to create indexes. According to the following documentation no table copy should occur but when I monitor disk usage it is showing that MySQL has high disk usage and data directory is increasing in size. Can anyone explain why this is happening.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable\G` and the index creation SQL/DDL.

Answer (score 2):

This is working as intended. The indexes are objects written to the disk. The index creation is also written to the online logs. Creating indexes is expected to take up disk space and cause I/O operations.

Answer (score 1):

That happens when InnoDB compressed tables with large amount of rows are being updated (no matter if the algorithm is in place). Large operations for ALTER tables, will use the "online log", which is expected to consume space. You can check this using `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` in the History Length line.

This happens always that you have large operations that need consistency across transaction history.

You can check this in the section "[InnoDB create index limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html)" . Some recommendations can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-create-index-concurrency.html).

If you share more details about the operation it can be useful to improve this answer.

Comment: `COMPRESSED` involves I/O, but it is not the complete answer.